# Extra Id in model

Tags: python, mysql, django, model

I am trying to build list of reports that belongs to a project. Each project can have a number of reports. Each report has to have unique ID, ie: 1, 2, 3, etc.. I am storing all reports in one table and that is why I can't use Django's autoField because I am already using it for Primary Key.

```
class Cawreport(models.Model):
    caw_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # report_id is unique for each project
    report_id = models.IntegerField(default=1)
```

What is the best way to increase report_id for each new report? What would you recommend?
Do you recommend me to find maximum number (report_id) for each project? Or, should I "count" report_id entries for each project and add +1?
Or maybe something completely different?

Thanks in advance

Edit:
I want to have this: Project 1: cawreport1, cawreport2, etc... Project 2: cawreport1, cawreport2, etc...

I want to achieve something similar to invoicing software where you are not able to delete and invoice without it being noticed. My client's client's doesn't want my client to be able to delete an cawreport and continuing at next number in the sequence. Actually, they usually reuse the existing cawreport rather than deleting it and creating a new one.

Comment: Do they actually have to be sequential, or is the only requirement that they are unique?

Comment: Some databases (like MySQL) do not allow multiple autofields. Furthermore I do not really understand why you do not use the `caw_id` itself? Why add an extra `id` that can result in more cases of duplicates, etc.?

Comment: What is `caw_id` not suitable for your usage? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Each project can have several cawreports. I have all cawreports in one table, and I want to have:
Project 1: cawreport1, cawreport2, etc...
Project 2: cawreport1, cawreport2, etc...

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `UUIDField` instead of an `IntegerField/AutoField`.

Answer (score 0):

Primary key is unique for each record in database so when you add new report related to Project it automatically unique.You can easily sort reports of Project in table. 
You can also add date field in reports for sorting.

```
class Cawreport(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    datetime =  models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

So there is no need of tracking the latest id of report related to project.

Comment: I was thinking about this a lot. My client wants to have report id because of their clients who wants to see that they don't trick them with reports. Similar to invoicing: Tax authorities don't want companies do to delete an invoice and just continue at next invoice number.